# wget - download sub dir when robots-off

Tags: wget

For example, I want to download the dir3 of this http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3.
The robot.txt exists on http://example.com/dir1/

It is working for,

```
wget -e robots=off .... http://example.com/dir1/
```

But not working for,

```
wget -e robots=off .... http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

It is possible to download a sub directory when robots=off ?

Thanks!

Comment: That *should* work. How exactly does it fail? What do you mean by "not working"? What happens? Did you check the log file (e.g. `wget -o log.txt -e robots=off … http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/`)?

Comment: **--2012-07-16 23:00:14--  http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/**
**Resolving example.com... xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**
**Connecting to example.com|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:80... connected.**
**HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden**
**2012-07-16 23:00:25 ERROR 403: Forbidden.**

Comment: The problem is, wget doesn't do DIR/ls on a directory, it can't. HTTP doesn't offer that. All it can do is follow a file like index.html which points to things.  Sometimes a directory has a default index.html that points to every file in it, but often not.  What do you see when you go to example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3 in a web browser? Do you see all the links to files in dir3? I doubt it. Then wget won't see them either. Maybe there is no such index.html or maybe it exists but is not readable from the web(which I guess is a common cause of 403).  You can do wget -d too, it gives more info.

Comment: Then why wget able to download all the things including dir3 when I run it as above first example?